# SignalR: Error loading hubs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Signalr doesn't load my hubs:

```
SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.
```

I am calling `app.MapSignalR();` in `startup configuration`.

I added to my cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure your startup class has this attribute:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyStartupClass))]
```

You can define your Owin startup class in your web.config as well:

```
<appSettings>  
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="MyNamespace.MyStartupClass" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Now I am getting also: GET http://localhost:18937/signalr/hubs 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Try adding this to your Web.Config: `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`

Comment: is already there. I also removed and added the Signalr nuget packages but without success

Comment: executing localhost/signalr/hubs gives me `an element with the same key already has been added`

Comment: turned out that I had two hubs with the same name. But I also hat to add the `OWinStartup` attribute

Comment: [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyStartupClass))] is not a must. You can also name your Class "Startup". At startup there is a mechanisme to locate your startup class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup

Answer (score 8):

Visit your site, ex http://localhost/signalr/hubs, and see if you can get a better error description there. My problem was that I had a generic method in my hub.

```
public void Update<T>(T objectToUpdate) where T : class
```

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure to add in your Startup class:

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

Solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

**Server has to know where your startup class is**

One option is like Rob wrotes:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyStartupClass))]
```

But there are other possibilies up to your requiremens. From Microsoft Docs (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup):

> Alternatively, you can define a fixed Startup class that will be used regardless of the environment by calling UseStartup.
>   This is the recommended approach.

Example:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
          BuildWebHost(args).Run();   
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```