# Angular C# WebAPI SignalR:- Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Duplicate of [Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260868/error-loading-hubs-ensure-your-hubs-reference-is-correct-e-g-script-src-si)

But no answer yet. Please help.

Comment: Mine was a stupid mistake! Hope this might help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a stupid mistake! Hope this might help others in future. I have AngularJS front end and C# Web API back end. So my routing was in Angular and Web API had a routing to make sure that angular does all the routing. So in my Global.asax file,  the code was as follows

```
string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(url)) && !url.Contains("/api/"))
                Context.RewritePath("/View/app/index.html");
```

I updated it as

```
string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(url)) && !url.Contains("/api/") &&  !url.Contains("/signalr") )
                Context.RewritePath("/View/app/index.html");
```

Now one problem is solved.